# automate outlook email error loading library

Tags: uipath

Hi i am trying to automate sending email with attachment of excel file however i am getting an error stating

```
Send Outlook Mail Message: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
```

the online solution mostly recommends deleting old office keys, however i am currently using 2016 version and is unsure what to delete, is there any other activity i can use to send outlook email. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your parameters of the "Send Outlook Mail Message" activity?

Comment: what package do you use